# Merging cases coming from several systems into one record type for history purpose

Tags: case, data-migration

I wanted to use a custom object, but I was given are to use the case object for the following:

In a systems decommissioning context, I was asked to design a means to  merge all data structures into a homogenous one for history purpose (i.e. Going from 10 record types to 1 record type 'History' in a Salesforce source context).

The solution I came up with was based on the following assumptions:

- All systems share common 'standard' case data (Ex: A case is always resolved or unresolved, has an ID, etc..)
- All systems have specific data on the case which are not always shared across systems (Ex: Epic name/link in a jira source system scenario)

In terms of implementation, the translation of this assumptions is:

- The merged cases will have a static/common section containing the shared information.
- The systems specific data will be contained in a polymorphic formatted in freetext fields (Ex: "*_Epic Link_*: Technical"|"*_Component_*: Kikoolol"). The data is formatted in order to allow for parsing if needed.
- The name of the source system will be stored as well for reporting or integration purposes.

**My questions:**

1. Does the approach common => specific parts of the records seem relevant ? Would you advise an other approach ?
2. Is there any workaround to replace the polymorphic fields that would allow me to handle systems specific data ?
3. As the system specific data fields are not really readable, do you know if Salesforce offers an alternative to this 'dirty-hack' ? Creating a readable field and keeping the formatted as 'technical' and hidden ?

Comment: are you merging the disparate systems into the Case object or some new custom object?

Comment: I wanted to use a custom object (more freedom, different related list, etc...) but the requirements I was given are to use the case object (same related list, etc...). Do you think using a custom object would bring a real asset or there are some things builtin on case to deal with these requirements ?